# Copy a dynamic range to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am trying to set a dynamic range onto a variable to copy the range onto another sheet.

On the last line I get

> "Run time error '91' , Object variable or with block variable not set"

Everything else works. The end rows and columns are found.

```
Sub AutoFilter()

Dim shWorkBook As Worksheet
Dim shPivotTable As Worksheet
Dim shCarrierRates As Worksheet
Dim shWholesaleLocation As Worksheet
Dim shPWLocation As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim shSegmentation As Worksheet
Dim MilageMatrix As Worksheet
Dim FullYearData As Worksheet
Dim StartForm As Worksheet
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

With wkb
    Set shPivotTable = .Sheets("PivotTable")
    Set shCarrierRates = .Sheets("CarrierRates")
    Set shWholesaleLocation = .Sheets("WholesalerLocation")
    Set shPWLocation = .Sheets("PWLocation")
    Set shSegmentation = .Sheets("Segmentation")
    Set shMilageMatrix = .Sheets("MilageMatrix")
    Set shFullYearData = .Sheets("FullYearData")
    Set shStartForm = .Sheets("StartForm")
    set shWorkBook = .sheets("WorkBook")
End With

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PWSelection As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set StartCell = shFullYearData.Range("A1")

'Find Last Row and Column
LastRow = shFullYearData.Cells(shFullYearData.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = shFullYearData.Cells(StartCell.Row, shFullYearData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
Set DataRange = Selection
PWSelection = shStartForm.Cells(1, 1).Value

shFullYearData.Range(DataRange).Copy Destination:=shWorkBook.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: `shFullYearData.Range(DataRange)` this is the culprit. shFullYearData isn't a worksheet. It's a variable. `DataRange` identifies the location (worksheet) completely. There is no need to specify where it is. Therefore this is all you need: `Range(DataRange)`

Comment: I made your recommended changes and I am still running into the error.  The reason I had the shFullYearData before the range was because I wanted to specify where in the workbook vba was to look.  Any ideas on other reasons for the error?

Comment: `sWorkbook` seems not only mis-named, since it isn't a book but a sheet, but also not specified anywhere.

Comment: Sorry didn't seem to copy over when Writing this question but I do have it defined and it is a worksheet called "WorkBook" (probably not the best name for clarity lol) in my workbook

Comment: The Dim statement is remmed out.

Comment: Are you looking at the edited version where that was already fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to find the last row and column.  Simply use `Range().CurrentRegion`.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FullYearData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkBook").Range("A1")
```

I strongly recommend using worksheet codenames, Read: [VBA CodeNames Explained](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/vba-codenames.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. However I noticed you use xlup and left when your starting point is cell a1. I was a little confused by that. But I was able to get passed the errors that pop up when you run your code.

```
Sub AutoFilter()

Dim shWorkBook As Worksheet
Dim shPivotTable As Worksheet
Dim shCarrierRates As Worksheet
Dim shWholesaleLocation As Worksheet
Dim shPWLocation As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim shSegmentation As Worksheet
Dim MilageMatrix As Worksheet
Dim FullYearData As Worksheet
Dim StartForm As Worksheet
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
With wkb

Set shPivotTable = .Sheets("PivotTable")
Set shCarrierRates = .Sheets("CarrierRates")
Set shWholesaleLocation = .Sheets("WholesalerLocation")
Set shPWLocation = .Sheets("PWLocation")
Set shSegmentation = .Sheets("Segmentation")
Set shMilageMatrix = .Sheets("MilageMatrix")
Set shFullYearData = .Sheets("FullYearData")
Set shStartForm = .Sheets("StartForm")

Set shWorkBook = .Sheets("WorkBook")

End With

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PWSelection As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long


Set StartCell = shFullYearData.Range("A1")

'Find Last Row and Column
    
''I cant figure out why you want to start at a1 and then do xlup and xlleft. that only 
''gets you to a1.
LastRow = shFullYearData.Cells(shFullYearData.Rows.Count, 
StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = shFullYearData.Cells(StartCell.Row, 
shFullYearData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range

''**here is where i made a change**
shFullYearData.Select
Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select


Set DataRange = Selection
PWSelection = shStartForm.Cells(1, 1).Value

''**I also made a change here**
shFullYearData.Select
DataRange.Copy Destination:=shWorkBook.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I now suspect that you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module. In consequence thereof you aren't alerted to the missing declaration of `StartCell`. In fact, `StartCell` is a rather useless range but if it doesn't get set your selection fails and that would cause `DataRange` to be Nothing, although this error should occur before the last row. Of course, the selection is quite unnecessary as well and may cause problems on its own because you don't control the ActiveSheet and there can't be a `Selection` on a sheet that isn't active.

To cut all of that short I recommend you re-write the entire end of your code. This code should work.

```
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PWSelection As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

With shFullYearData
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)))
End With
Range(DataRange).Copy Destination:=shWorkBook.Cells(1, 1)
```